# Unable to generate pdf using pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf when flask app is deployed on server

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

Getting the above error "wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-ubuntu' qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display Could not connect to any X display. "
When the application is deployed on the server. 
Using a Linux server here, the app is deployed using Nginx and gunicorn3.
I have used WKHTMLTOPDF in my flask application. 
I am rendering an HTML and generating a pdf from that HTML using pdfkit and WKHTMLTOPDF. 
Here is the code:

```
render =  render_template("pdf.html",single_form_data = fetched_form_data)
css = ['static/form.css']
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(render,False,css=css)  
response = make_response(pdf)
response.headers['content-type'] = 'application/pdf'
response.headers['content-disposition'] = 'inline ; filename=' + str(case_no) + '.pdf'
```

Comment: Looks like an incompatible version issue. Try `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: I tried that, still getting the same error.

Comment: I used Flask-weasyprint instead. It worked for me!